# Insect identification

Tags: species-identification

It is found in my apartment in Finland. I had to kill it to stop it from getting away before looking for the camera, but it looked pretty much the same alive and intact. It's length is about half a centimeter, and the younger ones look darker. It is often found in dark. Since their appearance, I often notice red and slightly itchy bug bite in the morning. The question is what is this insect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where in your apartment did you find them (what environment)?

Comment: @fileunderwater I don't know where did they come from, but they are just found on the wood and ceramic floors. The environment is warm and reasonably dry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It reminds me of [silverfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverfish), a common wingless house insect.

Comment: yeah, my first idea as well, and the environment fits. I first thought that the legs looked a bit long though. However, environment + movement patterns is a good way to identify them by.